# 8 queens puzzle: using random numbers causes infinite loop

Tags: c, random, infinite-loop, n-queens

When executing this code, my terminal hangs most of the time, but every once in a while I get the solution I want printed out. I know this is not the best way to solve the queens puzzle, so please don't comment on that. Thank you to anyone that takes the time to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int check(int number, int arr[]){
    int num = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(arr[i] == number)
            num = 1;
    }

    return num;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r, r2, i, v;
    char arr[8][8];
    int sum[8] = {0};
    int sum2[8] = {0};
    int row[8];
    int col[8];
    int cRow[8];
    int cCol[8];
    int count = 0;
    int sums = 0;
    int sums2 = 0;

    //Fill arrays and 2d array.
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        row[i] = 0;
        col[i] = 0;
        cRow[i] = 0;
        cCol[i] = 0;
        for(v = 0; v < 8; v++){
            arr[i][v] = '_';
        }
    }
    for(v = 0; v < 8; v++){
        sum[v] = 0;
        sum2[v] = 0;
        printf("%d", sum[v]);
    }

    //Loop ends when 8 queens have been drawn
    while(count < 8){    

        r = rand() % 8;
        r2 = rand() % 8;
        sums = r + r2;
        sums2 = r2 - r;

        /*If space on board is empty. If row and col value have not been used.
        Once a value of both row and col that have not been used has been reached 
        by random, mark that value between 0-7 as used.*/
        if((row[r] == 0) && (col[r2] == 0) && (check(sums, sum)==0)&& (check(sums2, sum2)==0)){

            sum[count] = sums;
            sum2[count] = sums2;
            row[r] = 1;
            col[r2] = 1;

            /*These two are used to store coordinate values in 2 arrays to be written               later.*/
            cRow[count] = r;
            cCol[count] = r2;
            count++;            
            printf("\n%d\n", r);
            printf("%d\n", r2);
            printf("%d\n\n", sums);
            for(v = 0; v < 8; v++){
                //sum[v] = 0;
                printf("%d", sum[v]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Print the coordinate values. 
    printf("\n");
    for(v = 0;v<8;v++)
        printf("%d ", cRow[v]);
    printf("\n");
    for(v = 0;v<8;v++)
        printf("%d ", cCol[v]);
    printf("\n");

    //Write the coordinate values. 
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        arr[cRow[i]][cCol[i]] = 'Q';
    }

    //Print 2d array
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(v = 0; v < 8; v++){
            printf("%c ", arr[i][v]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The infinite loop problem is because your program cannot "backtrack" if it ever gets to a point where it is not possible to legally place any more queens.  At that point, it just loops forever futilely picking spots that won't work.  Instead, to break out of this, it needs to "unplace" something it has placed already.  (Thus, you will need to explicitly detect when there are no more legal spots remaining in a column, row or diagonal.)